# reading string in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dev-c++

In the `Dev C++` compiler I can write and successfully compile this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string method;
  cin >> method;
  return 0;
}
```

but when I wrote the above code in `Visual Studio 2013 (console app mode)` I got this error:

```
Error: no operator ">>" matches these operands
operand types are: std::istream >> std::string
```

## EDIT

in `Visual Studio`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  string method;
  cin >> method;
  return 0;
}
```

I understand what the error tells me. But why in only `Visual Studio 2013`?

Comment: Your code compiles without problems in my VS 2013. Maybe you try it in a new project?

Comment: thanks for attention, but it's my mistake. that i forget " # " at the first line of project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to place header "stdafx.h" before other headers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: @coni If you indeed placed this header before other two headers then I do not know what is the reason of the error.

Comment: @coni Vlad is correct, if you indeed did `#include "stdafx.h"`, `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` you would not be getting that error.

Comment: @Cyber, @VladfromMoscow okay I understand what are you saying, but I did it guys.. I couldn't understand why the `VS13` gives me this error. I can post the screenshot...

Comment: @coni: As unlikely as it is, that may be helpful.

Comment: @coni Are there any other warnings apart from this error?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Cyber and sharth thank you but I found my mistake..

mistake is forget type " # " at the beginning of the first line :( and also i don't know how i did it?!

thanks very much. :) and sorry for wasting your time for me. :/

Comment: This may or may not help, depending on the content of your `"stdafx.h"`. There is no magic involved: Visual Studio's `stdafx.h` is a header which includes other headers. It's one of those _other_ headers which you needed.

Answer (score 1):

simple exlample for read string in visual studio :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::string str ;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << str;
_   getch();
    return 0;
}
```